# Abort Trap 6 error in C and debugging

Tags: c, debugging, memory-management, abort

Hey guys have finished my code and when I try and run, I receive the "abort trap 6" error. I have no idea what this error is and how to find out where my code is breaking. relatively new to c so thanks for hanging with me. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define HASH_MULTIPLIER 65599
int htsize;

struct NodeType {
    char *str;
    int count;
    struct NodeType *next;
};
typedef struct NodeType Node;

/*Function prototypes*/
char *lowercase(char *str);
Node **ht_create(void);
unsigned int hash(const char *str);
int ht_insert(Node **Table, char *word);
void ht_print(Node **Table);
void ht_destroy(Node **Table);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n = 0;                                                      // current number of strings
    char *line = NULL;                                              // line buffer argument to getline()
    size_t length = 0;                                              // buffer size argument to getline()
    char *token;                                                    // token returned by strtok()
    char *delim = " .,;:!\"?\n";                                    // delimiter characters for strtok()
    char *word;
    Node** Table;

    if (argc <= 1) {
        printf("ERROR: Usage: %s table_size\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    htsize = atoi(argv[1]);
    Table = ht_create();
    while (1) {
        if (getline(&line, &length, stdin) == -1)                   // read next line
            break;                                                  // exit loop when no more lines
        token = strtok(line, delim);                                // extract next token from line
        while (token != NULL) {
            word = lowercase(token);                                // store in word a copy of the token in lower-case
            ht_insert(Table, word);                                 // insert word into table
            token = strtok(NULL, delim);                            // extract next token

        }n++;

    }
    ht_print(Table);
    ht_destroy(Table);
    return 0;

}

/* returns an integer for place in Table*/
unsigned int hash(const char *string)
{

    int i;
    unsigned int h = 0U;

    for (i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++)
        h = h * HASH_MULTIPLIER + (unsigned char) string[i];

    return h % htsize;
}

/* creates a heap-allocated hash table with htsize buckets */
Node **ht_create(void)
{
    Node** Table;

    Table = (Node**)malloc(sizeof(Node*));                          //allocates memory for size of Table
    Table[0] = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));                         //allocates memory for bucket
    if (Table == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed.\n");                        //exits program if Table is empty
        exit(0);
    }
    int i = 0;                                                      //initialize int i
    for (i = 0; i <= htsize; i++){                                  //for loop to create htsize buckets
        Table[i] = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));                     //allocates memory for each bucket
        Table[i] -> count = 0;                                      //initilizes count
        Table[i] -> str = " ";                                      //initializes str to empty string
        Table[i] -> next = NULL;                                    //initializes next
    }

    return Table;                                                   //returns hash table
}

/* inserts word into heap allocated hash table*/
int ht_insert(Node **Table, char *word)
{

    int index = hash(word);                                         //runs hash function to create index for entry
    Node* entry = Table[index];                                     //creates nodetype "entry" = the index of the table
                                                                    //previosuly set
    Node* temp = entry;                                             //sets temp nodetype = to entry
    if (entry == NULL)                                              //if the index is empty run body
    {
        Node* newEntry = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));               //allocates memory for the new entry for testing
        if (newEntry == NULL)                                       //if new entry is empty jump to error
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed at insert\n");
            return 0;
        }
        newEntry -> next = NULL;                                    //if passed, set next to NULL
        newEntry -> str = word;                                     //make str = word
        if (newEntry -> str == NULL)                                //if the word is empty print error
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed at insert\n");
            return 0;
        }
        //strcpy(newEntry -> str, word);                              //if passed, copy word
        newEntry -> count = 1;                                      //set count to 1 to make sure the word entered is atleast 1
        Table[index] = newEntry;                                    //the bucket at i = to new entry
        return 1;
    }
    while (entry != NULL)                                           //if word is already inside of a the table run body
    {

        //if ((entry -> str = strdup(word)) == 0)
        if (strcmp(entry -> str, word) == 0)                        //if word is same as word at current i bucket
        {
            entry -> count++;                                       //add count by 1
            return 1;
        }
        temp = entry;                                               //set temp = entry
        entry = entry -> next;                                      //go to next entry in linked list
    }

    Node* newEntry = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));                   //allocates memory for new entry
    if (newEntry == NULL)                                           // if new entry is empty jump to error
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed at insert\n");
        return 0;
    }
    newEntry -> next = NULL;                                        //set next for new entry = null
    newEntry -> str = word;                                         //set new entry str = word
    if (newEntry -> str == NULL)                                    //if new entry str is null jump to error
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed at insert\n");
        return 0;

    }
    newEntry -> str = strdup(word);                                 //
    strncpy(newEntry -> str, word, strlen(word) - 1);
    newEntry -> count = 1;
    temp -> next = newEntry;
    return 1;
}

/* prints heap allocated hash table */
void ht_print(Node **Table)
{
    int i = 0;                                                          //initialize i = 0
    Node* entry;                                                        //nodetype entry
    for (i = 0; i < htsize; i++)                                        //for loop to run through each bucket
    {
        entry = Table[i];                                               //entry = ith bucket
        printf("HT[%d]: ", i);                                          //print ith bucket name
        while (entry != NULL)                                           //while there is information in a bucket
        {
            if (entry -> count != 0 && strcmp(entry -> str, " ") > 0)   //if there is an entry and its not an empty string
                printf(" [%s , %d]", entry -> str, entry -> count);     //print str and count
            entry = entry -> next;                                      //move on to next bucket
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

/* destroys heap allocated hash table */
void ht_destroy(Node **Table)
{
    int i = 0;                                                          //initialize i = 0
    Node* entry;                                                        //nodetype entry
    Node* temp;                                                         //nodetype temp
    for (i = 0; i < htsize; i++)                                        //for loop to run through each bucket
    {
        entry = Table[i];                                               //entry = ith bucket
        temp = entry;                                                   //temp = entry = ith bucket
        while (entry != NULL)                                           //while entry is not empty: body statement
        {
            if (strcmp(entry -> str, " ") > 0)                          //if str is not an empty string
            {
                temp = entry -> next;                                   //temp = next bucket
                free(entry -> str);                                     //free memory for str in entry
                free(entry);                                            //free up memory for entry
                entry = temp;                                           //entry is temp (next bucket)
            }
        }
    }
    free(*Table);                                                       //Free table
    free(Table);                                                        //free table
}

/*Convert string str to lower-case */
char *lowercase(char *str)
{
    char *word, *ptr;

    if ( (word = strdup(str)) !=  NULL) {
        for (ptr = word; *ptr != '\0'; ptr++)
            *ptr = tolower(*ptr);
    }
    return word;
}
```

The code is meant to take in a text file specifically this one:

```
Little Boy Blue,
Come blow your horn,
The sheep's in the meadow,
The cow's in the corn;
Where is that boy
Who looks after the sheep?
Under the haystack
Fast asleep.
Will you wake him?
Oh no, not I,
For if I do
He will surely cry.
```

output

```
HT[0]:  [i?  , -264221488] [under , 1] [oh , 1] [surely , 1]
HT[1]:  [i?  , -264221360] [that , 1]
HT[2]:  [i?  , -264221232] [horn , 1] [meadow , 1] [is , 1] [fast , 1] [asleep , 1]
HT[3]:  [i?  , -264221104] [cow's , 1] [corn , 1] [who , 1] [him , 1] [for , 1] [if , 1] [do , 1]
HT[4]:  [i?  , -264220976] [sheep's , 1] [where , 1] [no , 1] [not , 1]
HT[5]:  [wake , 1] [cry , 1]
HT[6]: 
HT[7]: 
HT[8]:  [under , 1] [oh , 1] [surely , 1]
HT[9]:  [blue , 1] [blow , 1] [looks , 1]
HT[10]: 
HT[11]:  [your , 1] [in , 2]
HT[12]:  [that , 1]
HT[13]:  [little , 1] [haystack , 1] [i , 2]
HT[14]:  [will , 2]
HT[15]: 
HT[16]:  [horn , 1] [meadow , 1] [is , 1] [fast , 1] [asleep , 1]
HT[17]:  [sheep , 1]
HT[18]:  [you , 1]
HT[19]:  [come , 1] [the , 6]
HT[20]:  [cow's , 1] [corn , 1] [who , 1] [him , 1] [for , 1] [if , 1] [do , 1]
HT[21]:  [after , 1]
HT[22]:  [boy , 2] [he , 1]
```

correct output

```
HT[0]: [under, 1] [oh, 1]
HT[1]: [that, 1]
HT[2]: [meadow, 1]
HT[3]: [cow's, 1] [for, 1] [if, 1]
HT[4]: [sheep's, 1] [where, 1] [no, 1] [not, 1]
HT[5]: [wake, 1] [cry, 1]
HT[6]:
HT[7]:
HT[8]: [surely, 1]
HT[9]: [blue, 1] [blow, 1] [looks, 1]
HT[10]:
HT[11]: [your, 1] [in, 2]
HT[12]:
HT[13]: [little, 1] [haystack, 1] [i, 2]
HT[14]: [will, 2]
HT[15]:
HT[16]: [horn, 1] [is, 1] [fast, 1] [asleep, 1]
HT[17]: [sheep, 1]
HT[18]: [you, 1]
HT[19]: [come, 1] [the, 6]
HT[20]: [corn, 1] [who, 1] [him, 1] [do, 1]
HT[21]: [after, 1]
HT[22]: [boy, 2] [he, 1]
```

Im on a mac using xcode and gdb, and im not sure how to check where this is breaking. Any help would be grateful.

thanks

Comment: Run your program in a debugger. It will show you an error here: `newEntry -> word = word; strncpy(newEntry -> word, word, strlen(word) - 1);`, What are  you trying to do there? It appears the dest and src parameters to `strncpy` are the same pointer value. That is specifically forbidden. The `strncpy` man page says: "The  strings  may  not overlap,". It's really not clear what you are trying to achieve there.

Comment: 0) `Table = ht_create();` need after `htsize = atoi(argv[1]);`

Comment: @kaylum thanks for the reply, im trying to copy the string in question, into the word part of my node structure , maybe im wrong but reading it back now it seems I try and do this twice? The function insert is trying to insert the current string into the hash table "Table"

Comment: 1) `free(entry -> word);` In the case of literal cannot free. (`Table[i] -> word = " ";`)

Comment: You can't just copy strings with an assignment operator since your `main` uses the same `line` buffer  for each input line. If you used assignment then all the nodes would point to the same buffer space. You probably want to either statically allocate a fixed size array in your `Node` structure and then use `strncpy` or allocate dynamic memory with `strdup`. Also, please take note of BLUEPIXY's comment. You are calling `ht_create` before parsing `htsize` but the former needs the latter.

Comment: @kaylum okay need some work i guess ill take a look thanks

Comment: @kaylum hey man updated the code and fnally got an output but its not correct and i have no clue why any ideas?

Comment: Regarding the calls to `malloc()`  In C, the returned value is type `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer,  So the cast of the returned value is not needed, just clutters the code, and is a real headache when debugging and/or maintaining the code.   Always check (!=NULL) every call to malloc(), not just some of the calls

Comment: the function `ht_create()` is using offsets to the Table[] beyond Table[0], however, the Table array is only large enough for one pointer, so any `Table[x]` where 'x' is greater than 0 is accessing beyond the end of the Table array.  This results in undefined behaviour and can/will lead to a seg fault event.   regarding this line: `Table = (Node**)malloc(sizeof(Node*)); ` to fix the above problem, change to: `Table = malloc(sizeof(Node*)*htsize);` followed by if( NULL == Table ) { perror( "malloc for array of node pointers failed"); //cleanup, exit( EXIT_FAILURE);' }

Comment: in the function: `ht_create()`, this line: `Table[i] -> str = " "; ` will not perform the desired action.  Suggest change to: `Table[i] -> str = NULL; `

Comment: the function: `ht_insert()` is calling `malloc()` then overlaying the (all ready allocated) pointer to allocated memory in Table.  this results in a memory leak.  What is should be doing is setting the values into the existing table entry at: `Table[index]`  then  checking to see if the current entry at: `Table[index]` is NULL,   It will never be NULL because the function: `ht_create()` already filled in all the entries will (especially the pointers) with values.

Comment: in function: `ht_insert()`, the second occurrence of this line: `fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed at insert\n");` is nonsense.   However, after correcting the code to use `strdup()`, then the check for NULL still needs to be there but the error message should be talking about strdup(), not malloc().   In general, the logic in `ht_insert()` is seriously flawed as it is setting an entry in `Table[]` before performing any checking to see if the entry already exists and similar oversights.

Comment: in function: `ht_destory()`, these two lines: 'free(*Table);   free(Table);` are seriously flawed, because all the entries in `Table[]` are already passed to `free()` so all that needs to be done is pass the 'array of pointers to char pointers' to `free()'  I.E. `free( Table);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT1:** done in ht_create() function to initialize Table array elements to NULL which was missed in initial post.
**EDIT2:** done to update modified ht_print() and ht_destroy() functions.

```
Node **ht_create(void)
{
    Node** Table;

    // Allocating array (of size htsize) of Node pointers
    Table = (Node**)malloc(htsize * sizeof(Node*)); <-- NOTE: Change done here, used htsize for allocation
    //Table[0] = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node)); <-- NOTE: Commented this line, stray code, Table[0] will be allocated in for() loop

    if (Table == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed.\n"); //exits program if Table is empty
        exit(0);
    }

    // NOTE: Code added for Table[i] NULL initialization
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < htsize; i++){
        Table[i] = NULL;
    }

    return Table;
}

int ht_insert(Node **Table, char *word)
{
    int index = hash(word);
    Node* entry = Table[index];
    Node *temp;
    if (entry == NULL)
    {
        // First entry at Table[index]
        Node* newEntry = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        if (newEntry == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed at insert\n");
            return 0;
        }

        newEntry->word = strdup(word); <-- NOTE: Change here to use strdup()
        if (newEntry->word == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "strdup() failed at insert\n");
            free(newEntry);
            return 0;
        }
        newEntry->count = 1;
        newEntry->next = NULL;

        Table[index] = newEntry;

        return 1;
    }

    // Go to the end of list at Table[index]
    // Also check if input word is same as one existing entry in the list at Table[index], if yes, increase repeat count for the word
    while (NULL != entry)
    {
        // Check if input word is same as word stored in current node
        if (0 == strcmp(word, entry->word))
        {
            entry->count++;

            return 1;
        }

        temp = entry;
        entry = entry->next;
    }

    // New entry in the list at Table[index]    
    Node* newEntry = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (newEntry == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed at insert\n");
        return 0;
    }

    newEntry->word = strdup(word);
    if (newEntry->word == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "strdup() failed at insert\n");
        free(newEntry);
        return 0;
    }

    newEntry->count = 1;
    newEntry->next = NULL;

    temp->next = newEntry;

    return 1;
}

/* prints heap allocated hash table */
void ht_print(Node **Table)
{
    int i = 0;                                                          //initialize i = 0
    Node* entry;                                                        //nodetype entry
    for (i = 0; i < htsize; i++)                                        //for loop to run through each bucket
    {
        entry = Table[i];                                               //entry = ith bucket
        printf("HT[%d]: ", i);                                          //print ith bucket name
        while (entry != NULL)                                           //while there is information in a bucket
        {
            if (entry->word != NULL)   //if there is an entry and its not an empty string
                printf(" [%s , %d]", entry->word, entry -> count);     //print str and count
            entry = entry -> next;                                      //move on to next bucket
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

/* destroys heap allocated hash table */
void ht_destroy(Node **Table)
{
    int i = 0;                                                          //initialize i = 0
    Node* entry;                                                        //nodetype entry
    Node* temp;                                                         //nodetype temp
    for (i = 0; i < htsize; i++)                                        //for loop to run through each bucket
    {
        entry = Table[i];                                               //entry = ith bucket
        temp = entry;                                                   //temp = entry = ith bucket
        while (entry != NULL)                                           //while entry is not empty: body statement
        {
            temp = entry -> next;                                   //temp = next bucket
            if (entry -> word != NULL)                          //if str is not an empty string
            {
                free(entry -> word);                                     //free memory for str in entry
            }
            free(entry);                                            //free up memory for entry
            entry = temp;                                           //entry is temp (next bucket)
        }
    }
    free(Table);                                                        //free table
}
```

Comment: hey man thanks for the help have entered what you sent and am getting a segmentation fault 11 error. i made some changes in the code above and finally got an output not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: I did not compile and test the code earlier. Found out that Table[i] NULL initialization was missed in ht_create(). Edited the post for that. Hope this helps you.

Comment: ht_destroy() has free(*Table) which is wrong, updated post with modified ht_destroy() and ht_print() functions.

Comment: My post is still using "word" member in structure Node (as per your original code posted initially). You have modified it to 'str' name now. So, you may need to search and replace for it. Thanks.

Comment: thanks so much i was really stuck it works perfectly now!